# Enumerar html en un textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Se que para enumerar en código html es :

```
<ol>
  <li>Este será el 1. </li>
  <li> Este será el 2. Y así sucesivamente. </li>
</ol>
```

El caso es que lo necesito en un textarea o de alguna forma. Necesito hacer que el usuario conteste a una pregunta y enumere sus respuestas, pero que el usuario no ponga "1-" sino que este salga automáticamente.

NOTA:

- La respuesta será enviada en un formulario POST para guardar despues en la BBDD
- Si ya esta contestada las respuesta se carga así, podra volverlo a editar

  ```
  <div ng-repeat="resp in respuestas">
      {{resp}}
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Utiliza un editor tipo tinymce asociado al textarea que permite dar formato html [https://www.tinymce.com/].

Comment: no puedo usar tinymce, debido a problemas con esta api

Comment: Yo he usado en ocasiones CKEditor con muy buen resultado, no sé si este te puede servir.

Comment: Si alguna pregunta te ha resuelto el problema recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo

Answer (score 5):

Basta con que crees un div que sea editable y meter la estructura de lista dentro. Cada vez que da intro, te sale el numero siguiente automaticamente.

Uso un `div` porque un textarea no interpreta el [html](/questions/tagged/html) del interior.

```css
div.editable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div contenteditable="true" class="editable" id="divEditable">

    <ol>
      <li>Este será el 1. </li>
      <li> Este será el 2. Y así sucesivamente. </li>
    </ol>

  </div>
```

Comment: Interesante, no sabía que eso podía hacerse. Yo dejaría la lista vacía con un solo `<li>` sin texto, saldría un 1 por defecto y a partir de ahí se puede ir escribiendo

Comment: pero esa informacion tb necesito enviarla por POST y despues en otra página puede moficar esa respuesta

Comment: @blonfu si, lo descubri hace tiempo con una pregunta en este sitio que me hizo investigar hahah puse la lista como la puso el op en la pregunta xD

Comment: @sirdaiz eso no sale en tu pregunta... y quiza sea muy amplia como modificacaion. puedes hacer una aparte no ?  te basta con un `div.innerHTML`?

Comment: @sirdaiz Claro, el tema es que no se envía con el formulario lo que hay en un `div`. Seguramente tengas que hacerlo con ajax pero como dice lois6b mejor plantealo en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno para lograr tu meta puedes usar `ng-repeat` sobre un arreglo o un arreglo-json y vas mostrando con `{{x.id}}` para cada iteracion. notese que `.id` es un atributo del array-json

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {id:1,name:"maria"},
    {id:2,name:"jose"},
    {id:3,name:"lucy"},
    {id:4,name:"gaby"},
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.id}}.- {{x.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: esto no me sirve debido a que no puedo editar, si quiereo añadir más información